# C++ construct asks for a struct that is not defined in .h

Tags: c++, constructor, enums

I have to do some changes in a project so I have to change some classes. This code was made by another person and I found a really weird problem doing my task (or at least trying until this wild mushroom appeared )

I have the next ClassA.cpp and I want to remove the m_ElemVar(enumType):

```
CClassA::CClassA(): m_iIntVariable(0), m_fFloatVar(0.0f), m_ElemVar(enumType1)       
{
   // more variables initizalized there
   otherVariable = value;
   ...
}
```

the .h :

```
#include "CMyElement"
class CClassA
{
  public:
     CClassA();
     virtual ~CClassA();
 private:
     CMyElement  m_ElemVar; // THIS is the var 
     int  m_iIntVariable;
     float m_fFloatVar;
     ...
 }
```

So the thing is that I don't want the `m_ElemVar(enumType1)` there because I will initialize it in another place, BUT if I remove it, when I build the class or the project it says:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘CMyElemnt::CMyElemnt()
candidates are CMyElemnt::CMyElemnt(enumTypeName)
```

while if I remove the m_fFloarVar for example it doesn't complains.... That confuses me a lot because as you can see in the .h there is nothing declared so I understand that this constructor should not expect anything.

I've clean and build it again, and also searched into google but nothing found so any help would be very appreciated. Thank you so much

Comment: Could you add definition of CMyElemnt to the question?

Comment: is just what you said, the constructor was parameterless with no polymorphism -.-'' thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `CMyElemnt` does not have a parameterless constructor so you have to call one that takes the enum. Maybe you could reassign it later if you cannot change its interface.

Comment: Wow! that's it! I went to the CMyElment constructor and that was... I added one without parameters (that's the great thing of polymorphism) and it worked. Also, I didn't know that this was what happened with a parameterless constructor so thank you so much for your flash help! [I would like to upvote your answer but not reputation enough sorry]

Comment: Is the error you're getting the same or slightly different?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is all objects of a class must be constructed in order for the class to be constructed.  If you don't construct one of the member explicitly then the compiler will do it for you implicitly using the default constructor.  Since `CMyElemnt` does not have a default constructor you will get an error.  The reason not initializing `m_fFloatVar` works is it is a `float` and the compiler can default construct a float.

To look at a different way anything you can write as

```
some_type some_name;
```

Is default constructable.  If you have do include parameters like:

```
some_type some_name(some_variables)
```

Then it is not default constructable and you need to initialize it yourself.